# unity c# changing button color wait 1 second and change the color again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a function that on click change the button color waits 1 second and then change the color again

this is what i wrote:

```
    public float showForSeconds = 1.0f;
    public Button DoBut;

    public void DoFunc()
    {
            StartCoroutine(DoTimer());
    }

    IEnumerator DoTimer()
    {
            ColorBlock colors = DoBut.colors;
            colors.normalColor = new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255);
            Debug.Log(colors.normalColor);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(showForSeconds);
            Debug.Log("I'm back");
            colors.normalColor = new Color32(255, 128, 128, 255);
            Debug.Log(colors.normalColor);
    }
```

it changes the color once to (255, 0, 0, 255) waits 1 second but doesn't change the color again to (255, 128, 128, 255).

all the Debug.Log are correct,
the first debug is: RGBA(1.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000)
the second debug is: I'm back
the third debug is: RGBA(1.000,  0.502, 0.502, 1.000)

WHAT DO I DO WRONG? :(

Comment: I tried to change every function of colors:

        colors.normalColor = new Color32(255, 128, 128, 255);
        colors.selectedColor = new Color32(255, 128, 128, 255);
        colors.pressedColor = new Color32(255, 128, 128, 255);
        colors.highlightedColor = new Color32(255, 128, 128, 255);

doesn't help. it still remains (255, 0, 0, 255)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you assign your color to a local copy. `ColorBlock` is a `struct` and as such you will get a copy when you assign it to a local variable. In order to have an effect on the button, you need to re-assign the `struct` back to the button.

```cs
IEnumerator DoTimer()
    {

            ColorBlock colors = DoBut.colors;
            // now colors is a local copy, so all changes you do to it will not affect the button.
            colors.normalColor = new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255);

            // you need to assign it back to the button
            DoBut.colors = colors;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(showForSeconds);

            colors.normalColor = new Color32(255, 128, 128, 255);
            // and again assign it back to the button
            DoBut.colors = colors;
    }
```

`structs` happen to be a bit unintuitive for this reason. So in case you have a similar problem down the road, look if you are using a `struct` somewhere. This has bitten me quite a bit with `Vector3`, etc. when I started out with Unity.

On a related note, this `ColorBlock` thing seems to change the colors for state transitions, only. So assigning a color directly may not have an immediate effect on the button's color.

The Unity forum has some [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/changing-the-color-of-a-ui-button-with-scripting.267093/) on how to set a button color directly (I just copied the relevant part from there):

```cs
DoBut.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's work good but now I'm facing a new problem. it appears that i need to deselect the button by code after 1 second. that's more useful to my code. any suggestions? :)

Comment: Could you, please, explain how does it work? In [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Button.html) for button there is no field for `colors` and in my editor I get `CS1061: 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'colors'`. What am I missing?

Comment: It just changing the colors like you say. I added "DoBut.colors = colors;" after each "colors.normalColor = new Color32(int, int, int, 255);"

Comment: the only problem now that i realized that i don't need to change the colors, just deselect the button after 1 second. now i'm trying to find how do I do that :/

Comment: Managed to deselect the button -------- EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null); -------- do the trick :) Thanks for everything :))

Comment: @GilJosef Please mark this answer as the accepted answer by clicking on the grey checkmark (✔) and see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)